# ng-class not working with $scope variavles defined in the controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope, ng-class

I can't make my ng-class work using $scope varibales defined in the controller

I tried this:

#### HTML

```
<nav  id="main-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"
            ng-class="{'on': some}">
```

#### JS

```
$scope.some = true;
```

When I change it to like this the class is applied

```
ng-class="{'on': true}"
```

Am im missing something?

Comment: can you create a plunker reproducing the problem?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this, so I'm curious what your app structure looks like. Is your nav definitely within the scope of the controller that "some" is defined on? Are any of your other classes overwriting the styles you are expecting to see shown by "on"?

Comment: Like @Michael said, primitive bindings to scope should be a concern (http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/).  
Just to be sure, are the view and the controller correctly attached? is the nav block a child of the tag where the ngController is declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be related to the fact that you bound a primitive to the scope. Can you try with:

**HTML**

```
ng-class="{'on': obj.some}">
```

**JS**

```
$scope.obj = {
    some: true
}
```

Comment: Already tried Michael, still the same. Tried to return as function too

Answer (score 0):

Solved it guys, It was leck of attention. 
Like AnFelipe suggested I was declaring my ng-class outside the controller, I put it inside and all looks good now.

Thank you all, for helping me out.